# How to take the cursor just ahead of a tag which is a child on contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I have this html:

```
<div id="myEditor" contenteditable="true">
    Hey Jony whats up. Are you up. Also need <a id="89" contenteditable="false">Philly</a> for today's presentation
</div>
```

How do I take the cursor just ahead of 'a#89' using jQuery? Had been going through various answers, but finding them a bit over complicated.

Heres a snippet I found, but of no worth till now:

```
function setCursor(contentEditableElement)
{
    var range,selection;
    if(document.createRange)//Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE 9+
    {
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement);
        range.collapse(false);
        selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
    else if(document.selection)//IE 8 and lower
    { 
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(contentEditableElement);
        range.collapse(false);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

Comment: uhm..let me see if i got the question, do you want to phisically move the cursor to #89 ?

Comment: no, programatically; using a function